# writing files in exported eclipse rcp product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am a newbie and I am working on eclipse-rcp and trying to build a address book with data saved in xml files.when I am running the project it is able to read and write into the xml file but when I am exporting it into a rcp product it is only reading the file but not able to write.

I tried searching Google but couldn't find the relevant answers so I turned to SO.

Any suggestions??

**Edit** This is my method where I am trying to read the file and writing it into xml file

```
public void writedata() {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID);
        URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("/xmlfiles/person.xml");
        InputStream inputStream=fileURL.openStream();
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(inputStream);
        ..................................................
        ..................................................
        ..................................................
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
        Bundle bundle1 = Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID);
        URL fileURL1 = bundle1.getEntry("/xmlfiles/person.xml");

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(FileLocator.resolve(fileURL1).getPath())); 
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your application from Eclipse it uses the expanded project folder for your plugin. Your XML file is writeable in this location.

When you export as an RCP application your plugin gets packaged up as a plugin jar file with the XML file inside it. You won't be able to write to this file.

For the file to be writeable it needs to be outside your plugin project, either in the RCP application workspace or in an external folder.

Comment: thanks nick..it works..i made the file to be saved in my eclipse product folder